# Extract Image Orientation Javascript

Tags: javascript, exif

While working on a web based project I was having trouble fixing the orientation of images captured from certain devices. I discovered that the orientation(along with a bunch of other image meta data) is available as a part of image exif and can be parsed too. After a bit of googling I found the below function which extracts the orientation from the image, and using that information I could correct the orientation while displaying on the browser. I have trouble understanding the below snippet of code. The first roadblock I hit was while trying to figure out the purpose of `DataView` and `getUint16`. I went through the MDN docs but it was not of much help to me. Could anyone help me understand this? Or even pointers to relevant resources would be very helpful.

```
 function getOrientation(file, callback) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {

        var view = new DataView(e.target.result);
        if (view.getUint16(0, false) != 0xFFD8) return callback(-2);
        var length = view.byteLength, offset = 2;
        while (offset < length) {
          var marker = view.getUint16(offset, false);
          offset += 2;
          if (marker == 0xFFE1) {
            if (view.getUint32(offset += 2, false) != 0x45786966) return callback(-1);
            var little = view.getUint16(offset += 6, false) == 0x4949;
            offset += view.getUint32(offset + 4, little);
            var tags = view.getUint16(offset, little);
            offset += 2;
            for (var i = 0; i < tags; i++)
              if (view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12), little) == 0x0112)
                return callback(view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12) + 8, little));
          }
          else if ((marker & 0xFF00) != 0xFF00) break;
          else offset += view.getUint16(offset, false);
        }
        return callback(-1);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
```

Comment: [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) and it's [getUint16](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getUint16) method are well documented on [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) - don't let the `Mozilla` scare you, they document web standards, not Firefox

Comment: There's a lot of bit-banging going on here, so unless you're willing to get familiar with the binary format of an exif header, I would try not to worry about it too much if you're sure it works. It seems a bit messy with all the "magic numbers", or hard-coded hexadecimal literals, but the gist of it is that it creates a controlled access to a raw memory buffer that allows bytes to be interpreted as various types of integral data.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks Patrick. I want to get familiar with the binary format of an exif header. What would be a good starting point?

Comment: Some of the values in [here](http://staff.cs.upt.ro/~marius/curs/cp/2013/exif.html) seem to match the expectations of the code above. I'll post a more formal specification of the data format if I find one.

Comment: [This one](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) seems to be a formal specification, though the language of the document might be a bit confusing to navigate.